# statsmodels OLS gives parameters despite perfect multicollinearity

Tags: regression, statsmodels, dummy-variable

Assume the following `df`:

```
    ib     c   d1   d2
0   1.14    1   1   0
1   1.0     1   1   0
2   0.71    1   1   0
3   0.6     1   1   0
4   0.66    1   1   0
5   1.0     1   1   0
6   1.26    1   1   0
7   1.29    1   1   0
8   1.52    1   1   0
9   1.31    1   1   0
10  0.89    1   0   1
```

`d1` and `d2` are perfectly colinear. Now I estimate the following regression model:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
reg = sm.OLS(df['ib'], df[['c', 'd1', 'd2']]).fit().summary()
reg
```

This gives me the following output:

```
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                     ib   R-squared:                       0.087
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.028
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    0.7590
Date:                Thu, 17 Nov 2022   Prob (F-statistic):              0.409
Time:                        12:19:34   Log-Likelihood:                -1.5470
No. Observations:                  10   AIC:                             7.094
Df Residuals:                       8   BIC:                             7.699
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
===============================================================================
                  coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c       0.7767      0.111      7.000      0.000       0.521       1.033
d1      0.2433      0.127      1.923      0.091      -0.048       0.535
d2     0.5333      0.213      2.499      0.037       0.041       1.026
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.257   Durbin-Watson:                   0.760
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.879   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.404
Skew:                           0.043   Prob(JB):                        0.817
Kurtosis:                       2.019   Cond. No.                     8.91e+15
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
[2] The smallest eigenvalue is 2.34e-31. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity problems or that the design matrix is singular.
"""
```

However, including `c`, `d1` and `d2` represents the well known dummy variable trap which, from my understanding, should make it impossible to estimate the model. Why is this not the case here?

Comment: statsmodels ols, wls, gls use moore-penrose generalized inverse, `pinv`, by default. So it's a regularized solution in the singular case.